# Extjs 4 showing JSON data (on demand) to grid?

Tags: json, extjs, store, extjs4

After URL has been reached, how to show this data to grid, autoLoad:true, only loads firstly defined URL, but how to "dynamically" show loaded JSON to grid?, Reload the data with newly called JSON?

```
buttons: [{
   text: 'Load1',
   handler:function(){
      myStore.getProxy().url = 'app/kontaktGrid1.json';
      myStore.load();
      grid.getView().refresh();
}},{
   text: 'Load2',
   handler:function(){
      myStore.getProxy().url = 'app/kontaktGrid2.json';
      myStore.load();
      grid.getView().refresh();
}}]

Ext.define('app.gridStore', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
        'name', 'email', 'phone'
     ]
});
var myStore =Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'app.gridStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '',
        reader:{ 
            type:'json'
    }
    },
    autoLoad:false
});


--Grid in Border Layout Center--
items:[{
xtype:"grid",
id:"kontaktGrid",
store: myStore,
border: false,
columns: [
    {header: 'name',sortable : false,  dataIndex: 'name'},
    {header: 'email',sortable : false, dataIndex: 'email'},
    {header: 'phone',sortable : false, dataIndex: 'phone'}
]  
}]
```

This isn't working, only loading from server no dispalying data.

Comment: Please provide the code that generates your store, and how do you stick it to grid

Comment: @Warung Nasi 49 -- I acctualy get a grid to load two times, but after refresh , again nothing...

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it,.. a *grid to load two times, but after refresh nothing*.. show me your current js by edit it again.. let us to see your code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, why did you load your json like that ? even it's working... this is the simple way :

```
text: 'Load1',
handler:function(){
   myStore.load({
       scope : this,
       url : 'app/kontaktGrid1.json'
   });
   //myStore.getProxy().url = 'app/kontaktGrid1.json';
   //myStore.load();
   //grid.getView().refresh();
}
```

from [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load), the definition of method `load` is 
*Loads data into the Store via the configured proxy*..

second, your probem is *only loading from server no dispalying data*..
it's mean no error with json, store, and the model...
i think your problem is in the grid panel..
try show us how did you create the grid

make sure your grid column is refer(`dataIndex`) to your json

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {text     : 'name',    sortable : false, dataIndex:"name"},
        {text     : 'email',   sortable : false, dataIndex:"email"},
        {text     : 'phone',   sortable : false, dataIndex:"phone"}
    ],
    //.....
```

Comment: I did this in a separate grid, it works, my problem is somewhere else, so thank you so much! Problem solved!

Comment: can you take a look at this post:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139215/json-data-not-showing-when-grid-in-dynamic-tab), maybe you can see the problem! Please help, stuck!